# SpatialJoin with "closest" option ok in python script but not when in arcmap toolbox

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

I have the following problem. I want to create a toolbox to obtain the distance between a polygon (Bldg.shp) and a point (pts.shp). I have started with a simple following python script:

```
import arcpy

bldg=r"C:\0_prg_dvp\SpatialJoin\Bldg.shp"
Pts=r"C:\0_prg_dvp\SpatialJoin\pts.shp"
Output=r"C:\0_prg_dvp\SpatialJoin\Test"
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(bldg, Pts, Output+".shp", "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "#", "#", "CLOSEST", "#", "HorzD")
```

All works fine. If I try to modify it to work in a toolbox as follow:

```
 import arcpy

 #bldg = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
 #Pts = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
 #OutputShp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
 #Output="C:/0_prg_dvp/SpatialJoin/"+OutputShp

 bldg=r"C:\0_prg_dvp\SpatialJoin\Bldg.shp"
 Pts=r"C:\0_prg_dvp\SpatialJoin\pts.shp"
 Output=r"C:\0_prg_dvp\SpatialJoin\Test3"


 arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(bldg, Pts, Output+".shp", "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "#", "#", "CLOSEST", "#", "HorzD")
 #arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(bldg, Pts, Output+".shp", "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "#", "#")
```

Arcmap crashes without any error messages, the output file is created but is empty. If I remove the "Closest" option, the toolbox script works fine (but I don't have the distance I want)...

Does anyone experienced this and have a fix? Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

How about trying the Near tool?  This will write the distance of the closest feature in a new attribute field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated, Near tool seems to work indeed but in my final version I also need to add few fields in pts.shp into Bldg.shp, therefore the use of SpatialJoin... Any other suggestions?